# how to avoid duplicate inclusion of a header file

Tags: c++, macros, declaration, header-files, definition

I have the following code:

```
#ifndef GOOGLESET_PHP_H
#define GOOGLESET_PHP_H 
zend_class_entry *googleset_ce;
#endif /* GOOGLESET_PHP_H */
```

For some reason if I include this header file in more than one cpp file, the compiler shouts that I am declaring `googleset_ce` more than once. Shouldn't the conditional macros above be enough to avoid this?

Comment: You've shown us how `GOOGLESET_PHP_H` is *defined*. Could you also show how it's *used* (presumably in that same header file)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `extern` keyword:

```
#ifndef GOOGLESET_PHP_H
#define GOOGLESET_PHP_H

extern zend_class_entry * googleset_ce;

#endif // GOOGLESET_PHP_H
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks you are declaring the variable in every file that includes this header.

This is one reason global variables are frowned upon.

Answer (score 5):

yes, but you are only declaring it once **per compilation unit**.

include guards only make sure you declare things once per .cpp that uses it.

So if `A.h` is included in `B.h` and `impl.cpp` includes both, then `A.h` is included only the first time.

In your case, you are defining the value of the include guard macro as a static pointer variable. So even if `impl.cpp` has it only once, `impl2.cpp` which includes the same files  will have them as well, so your static variable will have duplicate definitions at link-time

if you insist in having static variables (as Thomas said, it is usually bad design) it is better to wrap them in a function;

```
myClass* getInstance() {
 static myClass instance;
 return &instance;
 }
```

this is slightly better because it makes sure the variable is truly global, some architectures (like darwin) have that `static` variables are unique per dynamic library, not per process, so it might led to confusing behavior/portability

Also, and more relevant, static initialization always happens before main, and the order is not guaranteed. With static function variables, the variables are initialised "on demand" and so it is not affected by initialization ordering issues

to initialise a global pointer:

```
  myClass** getGlobalRef() {
    static myClass* val;
    return &val;
  }

  //and you set it at run-time, avoiding static-initialization happening before main
  * getGlobalRef() = new myClass();
```

Comment: So should it be declared extern and properly declared in a cpp file?

Comment: you *declare* it extern in a .h and you properly *initialise* it in a .cpp file. But read above for a better approach

Comment: This is a small learning project, How would I change the code so it does not break?

Comment: While I know I need to go the way you proposed, This is not the step I am in. I am just learning the behavior of the language now and how to debug it, Not yet into design and design patterns of CPP.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that it is a **linker** error, not a **compiler** error. You get a multiple defined symbol when the linker tries to put together the object files (`*.o`) for all the `*.cpp`files including the header file.

You would probably work around the problem using the `extern` keyword to make the symbol unique. And declaring it somewhere else in one (and only one) `.cpp` file.

Comment: Yes, with `gcc ... -v`, it is easy to find the problem if we use `gcc 1.c 2.c main.c` where only `main.c` defines the `int main()` and three files all include the same header `common.h` which defines something like `int bar;`. Then all three **source code** file (IMHO that one header duplicately included in one header will not cause the above problem.) will generate three independent object files by `... | as -v --64 -o /tmp/foo.o`. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278565/21294350, they will include the common header duplicately.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using "#ifndef GOOGLESET_PHP_H

```
             #define GOOGLESET_PHP_H 

            #endif /* GOOGLESET_PHP_H */"
```

you can use

```
           #pragma once
```

Answer (score 0):

If the header is included in several .c/.cpp files then indeed it's potentially declared in multiple .obj files.
You have to encapsulate it in a namespace or a class so it's not considered as a global variable for each .cpp file that includes it.

Answer (score 0):

lurscher has the answer.  If you're looking to share the same global variable across .cpp files, one way to do it is to declare it globally in one of your .cpp files, then declare it as extern inside the header file.

For example:

```
main.cpp
zend_class_entry *googleset_ce = NULL;

googleset.h
#ifndef GOOGLESET_PHP_H
#define GOOGLESET_PHP_H
extern zend_class_entry *googleset_ce;
#endif /* GOOGLESET_PHP_H */
```